# Como dar Loop em $_SESSION

Tags: php

pintou mais uma duvida...

Eu posso dar loop em $_SESSION, tipo:

Eu tenho esse código abaixo, dando loop em todas as imagens cadastrada dentro da tabela banner e pegando todas as imagens cadastradas no campo imagem.

```
<?php
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banner") or die(mysql_error());
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<label><img width="100" height="auto" src="../img_banner/<?php  echo $res['imagem'];?>" title="<?php  echo $res['imagem'];?>"/></label><br /><br />
<?php
  } 
?>
```

A minha duvida é se eu posso fazer a mesma coisa com a $_SESSION, tipo criar um sessão com o nome de banner e dentro dessa sessão eu cadastrar a quantidade de imagens que desejar, e puxar essas imagens através de um loop.

Se tiver como os amigos poderiam me dar uma luz de como executar o código?

Answer (score 2):

Sim claro que pode:

```
<?php
session_start();
....
$_SESSION['banners'][] = 'imagem1.jpg';
$_SESSION['banners'][] = 'imagem2.jpg';
$_SESSION['banners'][] = 'imagem3.jpg';
...
```

O valor de `$_SESSION['banners']` aqui é:

```
Array ( [0] => imagem1.jpg [1] => imagem2.jpg [2] => imagem3.jpg )
```

Despois pode:

```
foreach($_SESSION['banners'] as $banner) { ?>
    <img alt="banner" src="<?= $banner ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

isto irá produzir:

```
<img alt="banner" src="imagem1.jpg">
<img alt="banner" src="imagem2.jpg">
<img alt="banner" src="imagem3.jpg">
```

Ajustando isto ao seu código:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['banners'] = array();
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    $_SESSION['banners'][] = $res['imagem'];
    <label><img width="100" height="auto" src="../img_banner/<?php  echo $res['imagem'];?>" title="<?php  echo $res['imagem'];?>"/></label><br /><br />
<?php }

// Mais tarde quando precisar dessas imagens nesta ou noutra página faz:

foreach($_SESSION['banners'] as $banner) { ?>
    <img alt="banner" src="../img_banner/<?= $banner ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Valeu Miguel, mas te faço mais uma pergunta. Ao cadastrar novas imagens, ele criaria sempre um novo nome para a imagem cadastrada e seria incluida essa nova imagem no loop automaticamente? Me desculpe pelo abuso, mas fiquei com essa duvida...

Comment: Vou editar com o valor que `$_SESSION['banners']` teria